# flock always returns true

Tags: php, flock

If I call this script

```
<?php 
$file = 'file.txt';
$fp = fopen($file,'w');
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    echo "A";
}

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    echo "B";
}
```

I would expect that this file would never stop loading, because the first lock is never released and the script should wait forever in the second if statement. However, the script surprises me with the following outcome:

> AB

Why is the second `flock` true?

Comment: Because it's still the same process.

Comment: if you want to stop a process, try adding an exit/return/break. Hard to say what it is you want that thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) acquires locks in context of thread (sometimes even whole process). Locking same resource multiple times will "return" same lock.

This is intended behaviour, otherwise sample you provided would end in deadlock, you can't acquire lock and continue but also you can't release already acquired lock because you are locked. You would have to kill process from the outside.